# Framework error which does not exist

Tags: objective-c

Using a wrapper class from github to google directions api , 
https://github.com/Djengo/GoogleMapsDirection/blob/master/README.md

i am geeting an error :

```
AFNetworking file not found .
```

where i have this line :

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

There is no such framework in Xcode to add ,and i did not find it on the net .

What is this error ?

Comment: Try with `#import "AFNetWorking.h"" instead of
``#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't look very hard to not find [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (one of the most popular networking libraries for Objective-C).

You will need to download and install it. Be careful of the version you get as v1 is very different to v2.

You may be better off using [the afnetworking_20 branch](https://github.com/Djengo/GoogleMapsDirection/tree/afnetworking_20) and cocoa pods to install...

Comment: Thanks, i have already downloaded this one, and drag the folder to Xcode but the error still exist so i was thinking its something else. how should i put it on Xcode other than just drag and drop

Comment: Did you follow any documentation to install? To tell Xcode to create the framework? Look at using cocoa pods.

Comment: i could not find any documentation to install. usually to install a framework you can just drag it to xcode

Comment: i can't understand that. why do i have to follow 3 pages tutorial , to add some small library to my project ?

Comment: Go with cocoa pods, it'll make your life easier in future: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking